# Trigger event for each data in object

Tags: reactjs, json, object, foreach

As the title states, I want to show the right (hidden by default) solution for each individual riddle.

I have mapped 2 times through the same object, stories and placed the question and solution in 2 different `div`'s.

```
<div id="cardsContainer">
    <h1>All our cards</h1>
    <div id='cardsOverview'>
      {
         stories.map((story, index) => <Story key={index} id={story.id} title={story.title} desc={story.desc} grade={story.grade}  /> )
      }
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cardDetailContainer">
    {
        stories.map((story, index) => <Story key={index} id={story.id} solution={story.solution} /> )
    }                
</div>
```

I thought on creating an event listener inside a `foreach` and get the target that it's clicked on. After I get the target and parent, I can list through the same object and get the solution. Is this the right way of thinking, or am I oversimplifying things?

```
const stories = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'First black story',
    desc: 'Ga jij de eerste black story kunnen oplossen?',
    grade: 'Hard',
    solution: 'This is the solution for the first story.'
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Second black story',
    desc: 'Ga jij de tweede black story kunnen oplossen?',
    grade: 'Makkelijk',
    solution: 'This is the solution for the second story.'
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'third black story',
    desc: 'Ga jij de tweede black story kunnen oplossen?',
    grade: 'Medium',
    solution: 'This is the solution for the third story.'
}
];
```

Comment: Why not add an `onclick` to the `<Story>` component you’re already rendering, and use it to update the hidden/visible state for the corresponding solution?

Comment: @rayhatfield how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Story component that uses state to reveal its solution.

```
function Story({story}) {
  const [solutionVisible, setSolutionVisible] = useState();

  return (
    <div onClick={setSolutionVisible(!solutionVisible)}>
      <div>{story.description}</div>
      {solutionVisible && (
        <div>{story.solution}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you don't want to do that because you need the solution located away from the description (or whatever), you could move the state up to the containing component and keep track of what's visible there:

```
function CardsContainer({stories}) {
  // track which story is visible by its index in the stories array
  const [visibleIndex, setVisibleIndex] = useState();

  // use the visibleIndex state to get the currently visible story
  const currentStory = stories[visibleIndex];

  return (
    <div className="cardsContainer">
      <div className="cardsOverview">
        {
           stories.map((story, index) => (
             <StoryOverview
               key={story}
               story={story}
               // let the child component trigger a visibility change
               onShow={() => setVisibleIndex(index)}
             />
           )
        }
      </div>
      <div className="cardDetailContainer">
        {
          // render the visible story if there is one
          currentStory && <StoryDetail story={currentStory} />
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function StoryOverview({ story, onShow }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={onShow}>{ story.description }</div>
  )
}

function StoryDetail({ story }) {
  return (
    <div>{ story.solution }</div>
  )
}
```

This could be tweaked to allow more than one at a time if that's something you need, but it would follow the same fundamental pattern.

Comment: There is something wrong with the code, it gives an error.  i is not defined

Comment: Fixed. But this code was provided to illustrate the solution, not necessarily to be runnable exactly as-is. Don't just copy and paste it. Look at what it does.